# MySQL query running very slow on Composite key table

Tags: mysql, performance

I've got a composite key table CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF

```
__________________________________________________________________
|CUSTOMER_ID (PK NN VARCHAR(191)) | PRODUCT_ID(PK NN VARCHAR(191))|
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

In my batch program I need to select 500 updated customers and also get the PRODUCT_ID's purchased by CUSTOMERs separated by comma and update our SOLR index. In my query I'm select 500 customers and doing a left join to CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF

```
SELECT 
    customer.*, group_concat(xref.PRODUCT_ID separator ', ')
FROM
    CUSTOMER customer
LEFT JOIN CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF xref ON customer.CUSTOMER_ID=xref.CUSTOMER_ID  
group by customer.CUSTOMER_ID 
LIMIT 500;
```

EDIT: EXPLAIN QUERY

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key      key_len    ref     rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE     customer ALL      PRIMARY        NULL     NULL       NULL    74236   Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE      xref    index     NULL          PRIMARY  1532       NULL    121627  Using where; Using index; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

I got lost connection exception after 20 minutes running the above query.

I tried with the following (sub query) and it took 1.7 seconds to get result but still slow.

```
SELECT 
customer.*, (SELECT group_concat(PRODUCT_ID separator ', ') 
     FROM CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF xref 
        WHERE customer.CUSTOMER_ID=xref.CUSTOMER_ID
        GROUP BY customer.CUSTOMER_ID) 
FROM
CUSTOMER customer
LIMIT 500;
```

EDIT: EXPLAIN QUERY produces

```
id  select_type          table      type    possible_keys   key    key_len  ref     rows   Extra
1   PRIMARY              customer     ALL       NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    74236   NULL
2   DEPENDENT SUBQUERY    xref      index        NULL     PRIMARY   1532    NULL    121627 Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
```

**Question**

CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF already has both columns set as PRIMARY_KEY and NOT_NULL but why is my query still very slow ? I thought having Primary Key on a column was enough to build an index for it. Do I need further indexing ?

**DATABASE INFO:**

- All the ID's in my database are VARCHAR(191) because the id's can contain alphabets.
- I'm using utf8mb4_unicode_ci character encoding
- I'm using SET group_concat_max_len := @@max_allowed_packet to get maximum number of product_ids for each customer. Prefer using group_concat in one main query so that I don't have to do multiple separate queries to get products for each customer.

Comment: Run the query using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html) and add the results of that command to the question, it will help people (and you) understand what's going on.  But seriously, 191-char primary keys?  You sure that that's not a sligt overkill? :-)

Comment: Try creating an non unique index on CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF including the customer_id column only.

Comment: Probably more efficient (by a LONG way) to use an INT primary key, with your 191 character key being a different column and your related tables using the INT key rather than the long key.

Comment: In terms of database design, you could use autoincrement surrogate keys as primary keys on the customer and product tables. You could still keep the original long customer id and product id with a unique index on each. You could then have only rows with a pair of integers in customer_product_xref, which would make it way smaller and faster to do comparisons.

Comment: @fvu I've added the Explain query outputs :) I thought the default size of fields didn't matter. Should I be reducing the size?

Comment: Do some reading or searching on `dependent subqueries`, they run for every iteration of the outer select and are thus pretty disastrous for performance.  And of course the humongous index doesn't help, bigger keys require more storage and are significantly slower to evaluate.  Tarik and Kickstart 's advice should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @Kickstart I've changed the primary keys in CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF to be BIGINT(20) and repopulated the data. The results seem to be coming back only 10 seconds quicker. Still very slow :(

Comment: @Tarik I'm not sure how an autoincrement primary key field would help here when I'm searching against CUSTOMER_ID to get PRODUCT_IDs.

Comment: I propose to add an extra integer key on each of the concerned tables, i.e. customer and product. Then, have customer_product_xref have (int, int) as columns. This would make customer_product_xref more compact and the compare faster as it would only involve comparing 4 bytes or 8 bytes if you use a long int.

Comment: I just need another index for CUSTOMER_ID column. So I've got two indexes now. 1 for primary key and 2 for customer_id

Comment: How many product ids do you have for each customer id? If 191 bytes long you will only get ~5 back in the GROUP_CONCAT with standard settings, but with that amended I suspect the storage requirements will rapidly increase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright the speed of the queries in my question shot up when I created an index just on the CUSTOMER_ID in CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF table.

So I've got two indexes now 
PRIMARY_KEY_INDEX on PRODUCT_ID and CUSTOMER_ID
CUSTOMER_ID_INDEX on CUSTOMER_ID

Answer (score 0):

Your original version of the query is doing the `join` first and then sorting all the resulting data -- which is probably pretty big given how large the fields are.

You can "fix" that version by selecting 500 hundred customers first and then doing the join:

```
SELECT c.*, group_concat(xref.PRODUCT_ID separator ', ')
FROM (select c.*
      from CUSTOMER customer c
      order by c.customer_id
      limit 500
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF xref
     ON c.CUSTOMER_ID=xref.CUSTOMER_ID  
group by c.CUSTOMER_ID ;
```

An alternative that might or might not have a big impact would be to doing the aggregation by customer in a subquery and join that, as in:

```
SELECT c.*, xref.products
FROM (select c.*
      from CUSTOMER customer c
      order by c.customer_id
      limit 500
     ) c LEFT JOIN
     (select customer_id, group_concat(xref.PRODUCT_ID separator ', ') as products
      from CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF xref
     ) xref
     ON c.CUSTOMER_ID=xref.CUSTOMER_ID;
```

What you have discovered is that the MySQL optimizer does not recognize this situation (where the limit has a big impact on performance).  Some other database engines do a better job of optimization in this case.

Comment: first query took 1.45 seconds and the Second query did not return any result. In my question first query took 1.30 seconds and second query 54 seconds. I've changed the VARCHAR id length for CUSTOMER_PRODUCT_XREF primary keys to 20 character but still very slow :(

Comment: @CMR . . . I'm not sure why you have the frown.  You are learning about how the MySQL optimizer works.  I'm not surprised that the correlated subquery works well in MySQL -- that does not mean that it will work well in other databases.